# C++ Member Function errors "Undeclared Identifier" when used within another Member Function

Tags: c++, function, undeclared-identifier

I'm thinking this is in my declaration but I'm not sure. Have a class "Matrix" which creates 2-dimensional arrays of type int. The class has several overloaded operators to perform arithmetic, etc. on the class objects.

One requirement is to check that the matrices have the same dimensions. Dimensions are stored 
as two private ints "dx" and "dy".

So to make this efficient I wrote a member function of type bool, as follows;

`bool confirmArrays(const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2);`

is the function header and the declaration is;

```
bool Matrix::confirmArrays(const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2)
{
    if (matrix1.dx == matrix2.dx && matrix1.dy == matrix2.dy)
    {
        // continue with operation
        return true;

    } else {

        // hault operation, alert user
        cout << "these matrices are of different dimensions!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

but when I call `confirmArrays` from within another member function I get this error;

**Use of undeclared identifier** `confirmArrays`

Calling function like so;

```
// matrix multiplication, overloaded * operator
Matrix operator * (const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2)
{
    Matrix product(matrix1.dx, matrix2.dy);
    if ( confirmArrays(matrix1, matrix2) )
    {
        for (int i=0; i<product.dx; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<product.dy; ++j) {
                for (int k=0; k<matrix1.dy; ++k) {
                    product.p[i][j] += matrix1.p[i][k] * matrix2.p[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return product;

     } else {

        // perform this when matrices are not of same dimensions
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see your calling code I think.

Comment: Actually I think it may arise if the calling function is declared before `confirmArrays`--hard to see what else it could be.  edit--just did a little test, order shouldn't matter but maybe try anyway.

Comment: A wild guess: are you calling it from a `const` member function? You'll need to make it `const` (or better still `static`, or possibly `friend`, since it's not actually accessing the object it's called on) to be able to do that. Without seeing how and where it's called, a guess is the best you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator*` isn't defined within the scope of `Matrix`.  You've actually defined a global operator.  You need

```
Matrix Matrix::operator * (const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2)
{
   ...
}
```

and then it should be fine.  NB, If this had compiled, you would have gotten a linker 'undefined reference to operator Matrix::operator*' error since that was not defined.

Comment: it's defined as friend; `friend Matrix operator * (const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2);`

Comment: @frankV Ok, but in that case you are calling `confirmArrays` without an instance.  The solution there would be to declare `confirmArrays` as `static`.

Comment: @frankV I should have mentioned in that case you will have to call it as `Matrix::confirmArrays`.  You might also consider just making `confirmArrays` global, although you'll have to make some adjustments if `d1`, `d2` are private.

Comment: I want to keep those members private. Fix was actually making the bool function a friend also.

Answer (score 0):

The bool function is only needed to support the arithmetic functions. Some of those functions can be member overloaded operators, some can be friends. The trick here was to define the bool function as a friend also, making it accessible to member direct functions and friend functions alike, while retaining the ability to access the private member data.

`friend bool confirmArrays(const Matrix& matrix1, const Matrix& matrix2);`

Comment: Something's wrong here.  If `confirmArrays` is a non-static member function (member of `Matrix`), then it can't be called without an object as it is in `operator*`.